# With Python subprocess, How do I repeatedly run a shell command in a loop, without creating a new process/shell each time?

Tags: python, cmd, subprocess, pipe, popen

In order to repeatedly check if `abc.exe` is running (Windows), for example, I might repeatedly call the command, `tasklist | findstr "abc.exe"`, like this:

```
while(True):
    p1 = subprocess.Popen(
        r'tasklist | findstr "abc.exe"',
        shell=True,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE
    )
    out = p1.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8').strip()
    if out:
        break

print('abc.exe is running.')
```

I think this seems inefficient because of the overhead of creating a new shell/process for each run of the command. Instead, is there a way to keep one process or shell open, which can repeatedly call this command (and allow me to get its output each time)?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There are many ways to do this - you can buffer a shell and invoke the individual commands line-by-line by hand. You could use pexpect (a python library version of expect). However if all you're doing is checking for the process, you could use a library like psutil

Comment: You don't even need a shell for this: just call `tasklist` in python (**without** setting `shell=True`), and then process the output in Python.

Comment: Please tag your question properly. The _shell_ tag without any further specification usually means POSIX shell, but from your question, I think that you want to use either Windows CMD shell or Windows powershell, so please be specific.

Comment: @user1934428 my bad, updated

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to wait until `abc.exe` is running on a Windows system without spawning multiple processes in Python.

I don't have or use Windows, so this is untested, but you should be able to start a Windows command processor, e.g. `CMD32.EXE` or Powershell, and use its built-in facilities to wait till your program is running something like this:

```
command = """:search
             tasklist | find "abc.exe"
             IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 GOTO :running
             REM Sleep a little
             TIMEOUT /T 1
             GOTO :search

             :running
             EXIT"""

subprocess.run(args=['cmd32.exe', command])
```

As I am unfamiliar with Windows CMD32, that part of the code is adapted from [here](https://superuser.com/a/618217). I am merely suggesting a way to run that from Python, using multi-line strings.

Answer (score 0):

As [larsks commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76757494/with-python-subprocess-how-do-i-repeatedly-run-a-shell-command-in-a-loop-witho#comment135321140_76757494):

> You don't even need a shell for this: just call `tasklist` in python (**without** setting `shell=True`), and then process the output in Python.

A possible solution would be to handle the right side of the pipe in python, to allow `tasklist` to run without needing to use `shell=True`:

```
while(True):
    out = subprocess.run(['tasklist'], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
    if 'abc.exe' in out:
        break

print('abc.exe is running.')
```